# WMI Querying Thread Events - No results

Tags: windows, wmi, wmi-query

I`m investigating the WMI classes: [Win32_Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-thread), [Win32_ThreadTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/krnlprov/win32-threadtrace), [Win32_ThreadStartTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/krnlprov/win32-threadstarttrace), [Win32_ThreadStopTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/krnlprov/win32-threadstoptrace) for possible usage.

The only one that returns any data is Win32_Thread. The rest do not return anything, no matter how I tried to execute it (as Administrator, with PowerShell, with ready to use tools, with code).

Is there any specific reason as to why this is happening? My OS is latest Win 10 Pro x64.

Example tool for testing: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/simple_wmi_view.html

It would be really interesting and useful to see Win32_ThreadTrace working.

Any advice/help is much appreciated.

Comment: "The rest do not return anything, no matter how I tried to execute it" - the rest are _event_ classes - they can't be queried for instances, you [have to _subscribe_ to them and wait for WMI to call back](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/receiving-a-wmi-event).

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I see, then why doesn't the tool work to get notifications? It seems that it subscribes to most events.

Comment: Because the tool you're using is designed to browse WMI instances and class/schema data, not consume WMI events. What are you trying to accomplish with this? Write some sort of monitoring script in PowerShell?

Comment: I sincerely think that the tool is designed to subscribe as well, but maybe I am wrong so thanks for that. What I am trying to accomplish is far beyond my question... but to give you an idea: I want to trace threads created in process A by process B. I will do so using code, PowerShell was just for testing.

Answer (score 2):

After investigation it seems that @Mathias was correct and you need to "subscribe" for certain events, even though "some" websites state that you can manually query these...

In any case, and answer is here for anyone else that hits this in the future:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_ThreadTrace"
          
Register-WmiEvent -Source Demo -Query $query -Action {
$global:myevent = $event
Write-Host 'ProcessID:' $event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.ProcessID
Write-Host 'ThreadID:' $event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.ThreadID
Write-Host 'TimeCreated:' $event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TIME_CREATED }
```